# xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thanks！I've finish this problem! I add
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
{
  registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "/static/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}
in application, then the bug disappears.

Recently, in learning spring boot through the book "spring-boot-in-action", I encountered the following problems

When the program runs, I open the webpage and find that the line `"Xmlns: th= 'http://www.thymeleaf.org'"` has not been executed, and the CSS file has not been invoked.

Attached below are HTML source code, build. gradle configuration and web controller:

HTML source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Reading List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  th:href="@{/style.css}"></link>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Your Reading List</h2>
<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(books)}">
    <dl th:each="book : ${books}">
        <dt class="bookHeadline">
            <span th:text="${book.title}">Title</span> by
            <span th:text="${book.author}">Author</span>
            (ISBN: <span th:text="${book.isbn}">ISBN</span>)

        </dt>
        <dd class="bookDescription">
          <span th:if="${book.description}"
                th:text="${book.description}">Description</span>
            <span th:if="${book.description eq null}">
                No description available</span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(books)}">
    <p>You have no books in your book list</p>
</div>

<hr/>

<h3>Add a book</h3>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" size="50"></input><br/>
    <label for="author">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" name="author" size="50"></input><br/>
    <label for="isbn">ISBN:</label>
    <input type="text" name="isbn" size="15"></input><br/>
    <label for="description">Description:</label><br/>
    <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5">
        </textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

gradle configuration

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

web controller prtSc:(I'm not allowed to put a picture, sorry, so I put a link)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I can find this code, but

```
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
```

disappeared.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt5Nj.png

Comment: What is your requirement right now ?

Comment: I've solve he problem(The .css didn't work.)Thanks!

Comment: Please make a habit of giving the working solution as a reply to the thread, and marking it as the Correct Answer yourself. It can be confusing for the viewers when a Stackoverflow question starts with an answer.